# Create 4d array from 3d using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 3d

I've got some 3d data files with shape (100, 200, 90) that were frames from a movie. 
 I want to change the shape to (100, 200, 30, 3) to return the frames back to their original frame-state.

Is all I need to do is `np.reshape(original, (100,200, 30, 3))`?  I'm not convinced that's all I need to do.

I have also dsplit the original 30 times and then dstack-ed, but that just recreates the original shape.

Comment: in principal, reshape _may_ be all you need to do, though details and any other operations necessary may depend on the the ordering of your data in the 3-D array.

Comment: The frames were originally stacked in the correct order

Comment: sorry, I don't think I was clear. The order of reshaping the array matters, i.e.  in each block of 90 entries into the 3d array what is the ordering of the (I assume) RGB values. Is it made of 3 blocks of 30 or is it R11,G11,B11,R12 ...?  If they are blocks, are they blocks down rows or columns.

Comment: It is the RGB values in the order in which OpenCV wrote them.  In other words, I iterated through mp4 files and stacked the frames read into npy arrays.  As you probably know, OpenCV uses BGR.  Also, to be clear, each numpy file I am wanting to reshape consists of 30 frames stacked which each consist of 3 color channels.  So there are 90 channels 30 'frames' in each file.

Comment: Sounds like I need to split then swap [0,2] for each frame of three channels.  Looking into whether or not the order of the channels matters for Tensorflow.  Probably a good idea to be consistent.

Comment: Actually when I play these files they appear normal so I don't think the channels need to be swapped.